# A space in which sequences have unique limits but compact sets need not be closed

Tags: gn.general-topology

A topological space is KC if every compact subspace is closed.
A topological space is US if every convergent sequences has exactly one limit.
Does someone know an easy example of a US space which is not KC?
Thanks.

Comment: These terms happen to both 1) be terrible search terms and 2) have unguessable meanings if you're not familiar with them, so you might want to include definitions. 

Comment: Sorry, I edit to include definitions.

Comment: Take the finite complement topology on any infinite set.

Comment: That space is not US.

Comment: By the way, what do KC and US stand for?  I imagine KC means "kompact closed", but US is puzzling me.  ("unique sequence"?)

Comment: @Evan: Pedro forgot to tag you in his reply to your comment. Indeed, the finite complement topology on a Dedekind-infinite set is a classic example of a T$_1$ topology that is not a US topology.

Answer (score 11):

To create a counterexample X, start with the closed interval [0,1] (with the usual topology) and attach a new point z whose neighborhoods are open dense subsets of [0,1].

Observe [0,1] is a compact nonclosed subspace of X and thus X is not a KC space. However no sequence in [0,1] converges to z and in particular all convergent sequences in X have unique limits.

The finite complement topology on an infinite set does not yield a counterexample since every infinite sequence converges to every point of the space.

In general no counterexample Y can be a sequential space since if Y is a sequential space then Y is a KC space iff Y is a US space. ( Recall Y is a sequential space if every nonclosed set B contains a convergent sequence whose limit lies outside B).

Comment: pual Fabel, your nbohd around z is not clear

Comment: Let U be an arbitrary open dense subspace of [0,1], with the relative topology. For example U=[0,1/2) union (1/2,1). The set z union U is a typical open set in X which contains z.

Comment: Pual Fabel, Is $X\cup \{z\}$ still compact?

Comment: Yes, given arbitrary open cover, one of the open sets U contains z. The complement of U is closed in the compact space [0,1], and hence can be covered by finitely many of the surviving open sets in the original cover.

Comment: I think your question is a good one, since in general the closure of a compact subspace can fail to be compact, if the spaces in question fail to be Hausdorff. But in this case the complement of X is finite, so all is well, the closure of X is compact.

Comment: Paul Fabel, I was asking since I found the question, see https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4358229/707884, the user asked question has to do with your question and in the comments, they mentioned to your answer but I did know not how easy can one modify your example if it is possible

Answer (score 8):

Start with the one point compactification of the minimal uncountable well ordered space and then split the maximum point into two points.

Answer (score 5):

I refer to **COROLLARY 1** of [This Article.](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2316017?uid=3738280&uid=2&uid=4&sid=21101169814551)

In **COROLLARY 1** of it, $X^+$ denotes the one point compactification of the topological space $X$:

> **COROLLARY**: Let $X$ be a Hausdorff space.Then:
>
> (a) $X^+$ is always $US$.
>
> (b) $X^+$ is $KC$ if and only if $X$ is a $\kappa$ space.

So it suffices to choose a Hausdorff space $X$, which is not $\kappa$ space. then $X^+$ is $US$ but is not $KC$.

PS: The topological space $X$ is called $\kappa$ space, if A subspace $A$ is closed in $X$ if and only if $A \cap K$ is closed in $K$, for all compact subset $K \subset X$.

Comment: +1 for the link. Theorem 1 says: $T_2 \implies KC \implies US \implies T_1$ and none of the implications reverses even for compact spaces.