# T2 ⇒ KC ⇒ US ⇒ T1

Tags: gn.general-topology

In a topological KC-space, every compact space is closed.

In a US-space, each convergent sequence has a unique limit.

So, T2 ⇒ KC ⇒ US ⇒ T1, but the converse implications do not hold.

(a): Can you give me an easy example of a US-space that is not a KC-space?

(b): Is a product of KC-spaces also a KC-space?

Comment: For (a), see http://mathoverflow.net/questions/106571/a-space-in-which-sequences-have-unique-limits-but-compact-sets-need-not-be-close.

Comment: Are the first two lines definitions of KC and US, or are they merely properties that these types of spaces satisfy?

Comment: the first two lines are definitions of KC and US space.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out in comments, the first part is answered here: [A space in which sequences have unique limits but compact sets need not be closed](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/106571/a-space-in-which-sequences-have-unique-limits-but-compact-sets-need-not-be-close).

The second question is answered on math.SE in the question [Cartesian product of KC spaces](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/475762/cartesian-product-of-kc-spaces).

I am posting this CW answer, so that this question does not remain [unanswered](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/09/ok-now-define-answered/)